# Running Rest client using Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

Simple web-sevice is deploed on web server and its url is

*http://localhost:8080/jersey-example-new/rs/account/details/param*

Now I try to use this service via Jersey client by the way:

```
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/jersey-example-new/rs/account/details/andy").build());
```

Project dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)     at
com.javacodegeeks.jersey.main.RestClient.main(RestClient.java:21)
```

Comment: Do you have some api-jar on your classpath when you run it? You must run with the implementation, even if you compile against the api.

Comment: @folkol I have updated the question with the dependencies I have.

Comment: How are you running your program? Are you sure that the api-jar is not on the classpath when your code is executed?

Comment: @folkol I`m running it through Eclipse as main method.

Comment: @folkol all dependencies are in the classpath

Comment: Why are you using `javax.ws.rs-api` `2.0.1` with `jersey-client` `1.9.1`?

Comment: Andreas Schwarz: the api jar should not be there. Remove "javax.ws.rs-api" and see if it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dependencies are messy. Observe the following:

*Jersey 1.x* and *Jersey 2.x* use different package names:

- Jersey 1.x: `com.sun.jersey`
- Jersey 2.x: `org.glassfish.jersey`

*Jersey 1.x* and *Jersey 2.x* implement different versions of the JAX-RS specification:

- Jersey 1.x: [JSR 311](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) ([`jsr311-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api) artifact)
- Jersey 2.x: [JSR 339](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) ([`javax.ws.rs-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api) artifact)

### Jersey 1.x depencencies

To use *Jersey 1.x*, you need the following dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<!-- server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<!-- client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Read more about Jersey 1.x dependencies [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/chapter_deps.html).

### Jersey 2.x depencencies

If you want to use *Jersey 2.x*, you have to add the following dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<!-- server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, 
         use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Read more about Jersey 2.x dependencies [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html).

Comment: I've changed dependencies to 1.19 and turn of *javax.ws.rs* and seems it work but when I get json data `System.out.println(service.path("restPath").path("resourcePath").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));` it returns `Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://localhost:8080/jersey-example-new/rs/account/details/andy/restPath/resourcePath returned a response status of 404 Not Found`

Comment: @AndreasSchwarz Double check your URL. It might be wrong.

Comment: @AndreasSchwarz If the URL works in the browser, it should work in your REST client too. I cannot figure out what you are doing: in the question you mentioned you are trying to access the URL http://localhost:8080/jersey-example-new/rs/account/details/param. In your comment the URL is different: http://localhost:8080/jersey-example-new/rs/account/details/andy/restPath/resourcePath.

Comment: @AndreasSchwarz As I told you before, you are trying different URLs in your browser and in your REST client. Remember, if your endpoints do not match the requested URL, you'll get a `404 Not Found` error.